# Count of rides in each week over the last 12 weeks

Tags: sql, postgresql

Assume that we have the following tables, with columns as indicated:

```
Rides
    ride_id
    start_time
    end_time
    passenger_id
    driver_id
    ride_region      
    is_completed (Y/N)

Drivers
    driver_id
    onboarding_time
    home_region
```

Write a query that we could use to create a plot of the total count of rides completed in our San Francisco region, for each week over the last 12 weeks.

I have used `datepart` to get the count for every week. But I am not sure how to include the clause which outputs last 12 weeks from `TODAY`. My code will give a count for week 1 to 12 from the earliest start time.
Please check my code and correct me.

```
    SELECT datepart(week, START_TIME), COUNT(RIDE_ID)
    FROM RIDES
    WHERE is completed = 'Y' AND ride_region ='San Francisco' AND 
    datepart(week, START_TIME) <= 12
    group by `datepart(week, START_TIME)`;
```

I expect count output for last 12 weeks based on week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
AND datepart(week, START_TIME) <= 12
```

use this

```
AND START_TIME > current_date - interval '84 day'
```

because you want all the rows from the last 12 weeks = 84 days
and `group by datepart(week, START_TIME)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the last 12 weeks from current_date

```
SELECT datepart(week, START_TIME), COUNT(RIDE_ID)
FROM RIDES
WHERE is completed = 'Y' 
AND ride_region ='San Francisco' 
AND datepart(week, START_TIME) between (date_trunc('week', current_date) -12) 
      AND date_trunc('week', current_date) 
group by datepart(week, START_TIME);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit complicated, because you probably don't want partial weeks.  So, subtracting 12 weeks (or 84 days) may not be sufficient.

I would recommend logic more like this:

```
where start_time >= date_trunc('week', curdate()) - interval '12 week') and
      start_time < date_trunc('week', curdate())
```

This gives the last 12 *full* weeks of data, based on calendar weeks.

You have already decided to use the canonical definition of week, so this makes sense.  Alternatively, you could have the definition of week starting on any day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

Select ride_id, start_time, end_time, datediff(week,start_time,end_time) as [WEEKLYRIDE],
Count(ride_id) AS (TOTALRIDES)
From rides
Where ride_region = ‘San Francisco’
And ride_completed = ‘Y’
And datediff(wk,start_time, end_time) BETWEEN 1 and 12
GROUP BY datediff(wk,start_time, end_time)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).